# Can not copy text from CHM file

Tags: 10.04, software-recommendation

I have a download book which is in CHM format. When I open the book in Windows OS, I can copy the text in the book and paste it. However, when I read the book under Ubuntu OS, I can not copy text from this book.

Why is that, and how do I enable text copy from CHM files in Ubuntu?

Comment: What is the name of your program that handles CHM files on Ubuntu? I have xCHM on Ubuntu 11.04 and it works as expected - I can copy text

Comment: Yes, after I change to use xCHM, it can copy

Answer (score 1):

*(OP Solved Problem)*

> Yes, after I change to use xCHM, it can copy